# Default value for dropdown option in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the `dropdown` option in `Yii` like this

```
<?php echo $form->dropdownList($students,'student_name', CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'student_name', 'student_name'), array('selected'=>'Choose One')); ?>
```

Which `html output` is something like this

```
<select selected="selected" name="Students[student_name]" id="Students_student_name">
<option value="Alex">Alex</option>
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Johny">Johny</option>
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

But I want the `Select One` should be the `default selected value for the dropdown options`.So that by default there will be `Select One` when no option is selected.

**[UPDATE]**

It is taking `Select One` as a option when I tried `array('prompt'=>'Choose One')` and `array('empty'=>'Choose One')` also.

Comment: is this happening only on update or also on create action/views?

Comment: It's unclear what you're expecting - if there is no selection, what do you want?  Do you want the dropdown to have a choice of "Choose One" displayed/selected?  Are you expecting that if they make no choice, and submit the form, that a default value be choosen?  Or something else?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're using the wrong key for the default selected value.

Try:

```
// array('prompt'=>'Choose One')
echo $form->dropdownList($students,'student_name', CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'student_name', 'student_name'), array('prompt'=>'Choose One')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute named `empty`

```
echo $form->dropdownList(
    $students,
    'student_name', 
     CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'student_name', 'student_name'),   
     array('empty'=>'Choose One') // boom!
);
```

Comment: i'm using `empty` all the time and its working. Does your code returns any array or its empty list? I'm loking at variable `$students` and i get confused because it should be single record not multiple as variable says to me. Try `prompt` as @ben-rowe suggest you. it's also valid attribute and give feedback about that. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail

Comment: @NewBie Your model `$students` contains pre-selected value for `student_name`. You have to reset it before rendering view like for example: `$students->student_name = null;` Then adding an `empty` option like described in that answer will work for you.

Comment: @johnathan so how to make it reset?

Comment: would `array_merge(array(''=>'Select One'),CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'student_name', 'student_name'))` work, just prepend the value to the beginning of the `listData()`?

Answer (score 1):

When ever have needed to do this I simply add to the array generated by listData.

```
<?php echo $form->dropdownList($students,'student_name', array(''=>'Select One') + CHtml::listData(Students::model()->findAll(), 'student_name', 'student_name')); ?>
```

Has always worked fine for me.